# Javascript regex splitting words in a comma separated string

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to split a comma separated string using regex.

```
var a = 'hi,mr.007,bond,12:25PM'; //there are no white spaces between commas
var b = /(\S+?),(?=\S|$)/g;
b.exec(a); // does not catch the last item.
```

Any suggestion to catch all the items.

Comment: how about `a.split(',')`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use a negated character class:

```
/([^,]+)/g
```

will match groups of non-commas.

```
< a = 'hi,mr.007,bond,12:25PM'
> "hi,mr.007,bond,12:25PM"
< b=/([^,]+)/g
> /([^,]+)/g
< a.match(b)
> ["hi", "mr.007", "bond", "12:25PM"]
```

Comment: What if I have to match `Juan Gastelum` from `Juan Gastelum, media@nilc.org, 213-375-3149`

Comment: Try it and see.

Comment: I mean I am getting the list but I just exactly want `Juan Gastelum` and not list.

Answer (score 7):

Why not just use `.split`?

```
>'hi,mr.007,bond,12:25PM'.split(',')
["hi", "mr.007", "bond", "12:25PM"]
```

If you *must* use regex for some reason:

```
str.match(/(\S+?)(?:,|$)/g)
["hi,", "mr.007,", "bond,", "12:25PM"]
```

(note the inclusion of commas).

Answer (score 1):

If you are passing a CSV file, some of your values may have got double-quotes around them, so you may need something a little more complicated. For example:

```
Pattern splitCommas = java.util.regex.Pattern.compile("(?:^|,)((?:[^\",]|\"[^\"]*\")*)");

Matcher m = splitCommas.matcher("11,=\"12,345\",ABC,,JKL");

while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println( m.group(1));
}
```

or in Groovy:

```
java.util.regex.Pattern.compile('(?:^|,)((?:[^",]|"[^"]*")*)')
        .matcher("11,=\"12,345\",ABC,,JKL")
            .iterator()
                .collect { it[1] }
```

This code handles:

- blank lines (with no values or commas on them)
- empty columns, including the last column being empty
- handles values wrapped in double-quotes, including commas inside the double-quotes
- but does not handle two double-quotes used for escaping a double quote-itself

The pattern consists of:

- `(?:^|,)` matches the start of the line or a comma after the last column, but does not add that to the group
- `((?:[^",]|"[^"]*")*)` matches the value of the column, and consists of:

  - a collecting group, which collects zero or more characters that are:

    - `[^",]` is a character that's not a comma or a quote
    - `"[^"]*"` is a double-quote followed by zero or more other characters ending in another double-quote
  - those are or-ed together, using a non-collecting group: `(?:[^",]|"[^"]*")`
  - use a `*` to repeat the above any number of times: `(?:[^",]|"[^"]*")*`
  - and into a collecting group to give the columns value: `((?:[^",]|"[^"]*")*)`

Doing escaping of double quotes is left as an exercise to the reader